# SQL LOADER ERROR_0102

Tags: oracle

Below is my Table structure and .CTL FILE & .CSV file while loading data i am always getting error on first row & other data is getting is getting loaded. if i left a complete blank line on first record all data gets inserted.
can you please help us why i am getting error on first record.

TABLE_STRUCTURE

```
ING_DATA
(
  ING_COMPONENT_ID  NUMBER               NOT NULL,
  PARENT_ING_ID     NUMBER               NOT NULL,
  CHILD_ING_ID      NUMBER               NOT NULL,
  PERCENTAGE               NUMBER(7,4)          NOT NULL
);
```

CTL FILE

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE  'C:\Users\pramod.uthkam\Desktop\Apex\Database\SQL LOADER-PROD\ING_COMPONENT\ingc.csv'
BADFILE 'D:\SQl Loader\bad_orders.txt'
INTO TABLE ING_data
FIELDS
TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
     TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
ING_Component_ID ,
Parent_ING_ID ,
Child_ING_ID  ,
Percentage 
)
```

CSV FILE

```
1,3,4,95.0000
2,3,5,5.0000
3,6,7,5.0000
4,6,4,95.0000
5,18,19,19.0000
6,18,20,80.0000
7,18,21,1.0000
8,34,35,85.0000
```

LOG FILE

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table ING_COMPONENT, column ING_COMPONENT_ID.
ORA-01722: invalid number


Table ING_COMPONENT:
  7 Rows successfully loaded.
  1 Row not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.

Space allocated for bind array:                  66048 bytes(64 rows)
Read   buffer bytes: 1048576

Total logical records skipped:          0
Total logical records read:             7
Total logical records rejected:         1
Total logical records discarded:        0
```

BAD FILE

```
1,3,4,95.0000
```

Comment: You posted the strucure of ING_DATA, but your CTL refers to ING_Component

Comment: Hi Aleksej 
Thanks for looking in to it.I have corrected the Table name from ING_Component to ING_DATA.problem comes with only First row if i leave blank line at first row the data gets inserted properly .i have exported this data from SQL server and Trying to load it in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

I tried loading your file by creating it as is. For me it runs fine. All 8 rows got loaded. No issues. I was trying in Red Hat Linux.

Then I tried 2 things.

`dos2unix myctl.ctl`

Ran SQLLDR. All rows got inserted.
Then I tried:

`unix2dos myctl.ctl`

RAN SQLLDR again, all 8 records rejected. So what I believe is that, your first record line ending is not as per you sqlplus readable format. When you enter a blank line manually, your default environment (like in my case UNIX) creates the correct line ending, and the records get read. I'm not sure, but I assume this, based on my own try as above.

So lets say you are loading this file in windows(I think this because your path looks like :)) In your csv file, give a blank line in beginning, then remove it, and do the same thing after first record also(give a blank line after first record, then remove it). Then try again. Maybe it works if the issue is what I suspect.

Comment: Hi Rogue coder , you are correct in Unix it runs fine and all records gets inserted but in windows as you said first record line ending might not be proper i have done the same thing give a blank line in beginning, then remove it and then all records gets inserted.but still i don't understand why first record is not readable as sqlplus format as i am directly exporting data into .csv file from a query in sql server database.

Comment: Sorry, no experience with SQL Server, so can't explain that.